# Hover effect in email signatures. How?

Tags: html, css, email, outlook

I'm trying to add a hover effect, so my logo changes with hover.

I have managed to do that, however, I'm trying to add it as an email signature on outlook but I have no idea how.

I tried copying it like I usually do with a non-interactive email signature but that didn't work.

Here's an example for you to grasp what I'm trying to do.

```css
.photo {
  width: 130px;
  height: 195px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
}
.photo .img-top {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
}
.photo:hover .img-top {
  display: inline;
}
.photo:hover img:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Change Image on Hover in CSS</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
  <body>
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="pic1.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="first">
    <img src="pic2.jpg" class="img-top"  width="100" height="100" alt="second">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have greatly overestimated the html and css that is supported in email bodies. To give you an idea, even your `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag isn't supported because it's too new; html 5.

Your code is "too new".

In a few words, you can't.

Take a look at [email-campaign-html-and-css-support](https://www.pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support)

Also, [Hover over text in Outlook](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_winother-mso_365hp/hover-over-text-in-outlook/456eda75-ebef-4cf2-879d-95d65e6c7ba6) at Microsoft forums regarding your Outlook signature question under comments.

Comment: after reading the article I now understand that some attributes are not supported and thank you for mentioning that, however, I have found online email signature generators that offer such thing in their paid feature, that's why I tried to do it from scratch, do you have any idea how they may have done this?

Comment: Whatever they offer, needs to ultimately be supported by the email client that is going to be receiving the message. With limited css/html support, I would have to wonder how they ultimately accomplish this without breaking the client user experience. Surely they provide a working template?